# How do I bind row count of a datagrid to a textblock text whose specific column has specific values?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a datagrid in my WPF c# application (MVVM pattern) whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a `ICollectionView`, something like :

```
public ICollectionView PendingBills { get; private set; }

    public BillsViewModel()
    {
        _penBills = m.PBills;

        PendingBills = new ListCollectionView(_penBills)
        {
            Filter = o => ((Bills)o).PaidOn==""
        };
    }

....
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PendingBills}"
```

Now I've bound the row count of the datagrid to a textblock text using something like (which shows the count of all rows after filter)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PendingBills.Count, StringFormat='Total Pending Bills :\ {0}'}" ...
```

But I also want to bind the row count to a different textblock where say the `BillNo` column data of the database has a specific text or maybe its null or non-empty something like that.

How do I do that ? Do I need to use some sort of `IValueConverter` to this and if yes how ?

UPDATE

I've tried to a property to the viewmodel like

```
private int _cnt;

public int Cnt
{
    get
    {
        if (_cnt == 0) _cnt = _penBills.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PaidOn.ToString())).Count();
        return _cnt;
    }

    set
    {
        _cnt =value;
    }
}
```

and then use it like `Text="{Binding Cnt}"` but it does not work.

Comment: Add a property to the ViewModel and populate it when the collection changes.

Comment: @TamalBanerjee: You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Cnt` property whenever you want the view to be updated. What type is `_penBills`?

Comment: @mm8 I tried that but didn't do the job, btw the type is `private List<Bills> _penBills;`, the count just does not change.

Comment: What did you try? When do you raise the event? And what does "not working" mean?

Comment: @mm8 check here https://codeshare.io/oQgReb , when I run the app the count of all rows that have `PaidOn` value as empty show up, even when I have not selected anything in the combo box. It is supposed to work like when I select an item `SelectedCBItem` the database data get filtered and shown in the datagrid and the total row count is shown in one textblock and the row count of `PaidOn` empty rows should show in another textblock

Comment: Where am I suppose to see that you call the event...?

Comment: @mm8 the event is when the filter is applied `PendingBills = new ListCollectionView(_penBills) { Filter = o => ((Bills)o).Party == SelectedCBItem };`, the filtered data is shown in the datagrid and the count is based on the items displayed in the datagrid.

Comment: What? Where are you setting `Cnt`?

Comment: The property is inside the `BillsViewModel` , should it be somewhere else ? I know I'm setting it improperly thats why its not updating but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

While you could always use a converter yes (and this is my own opinion based on experience here) you may just want to do this in the code behind.
You could have a property stored that gets the count you are looking for based on a linq query and simply bind to that.

Let me give an example.
you could get back the elements that match on some text:

```
var countOfMatches = yourlist.Where(x => x.SOMEVALUE == SOMETEXT).Count();
```

or you could go by some numeric condition:

```
var countOfMatches = yourList.Where(x => x.Price > 400).Count();
```

I hope this is a helpful answer to you.

In short I am pretty much saying that if you want a custom count based on this list you are better off creating a property for it and setting it with a query.

Based on your edit:
change the query to:

```
_penBills.Where(x => x.PaidOn.ToString() != string.Empty).Count();
```

(which is just a nitpick really)

as for your binding can you confirm that the observable collection for bills and this new integer property are stored on a view model that is the data context for this xaml.cs view?

Comment: I've already thought about that approach but cannot figure out how to properly implement it.

Comment: I am more than happy to help if you would like me to

Comment: I've updated my post to show how I tried to do it but it didn't work.

Comment: I've shared some snippets of my code here https://codeshare.io/oQgReb  ,hope it gives you some idea. Anyways it is not working as intended

Comment: have you checked my code snippet ?